# The use of the adjective "narrow" as an adverb

Tags: adjectives, phrase-choice

Tell me please if the following use of the adjective is correct.

> You hands are too far apart. Grab the bar **narrower** and chin up.

What I want to communicate is hands being closer together is better. I suspect my use of the adjective isn't correct, but I cannot come up with a more brief phrase to communicate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The adverb form of *narrow* is ***narrowly***, and like adverbs in general it doesn't have comparative forms - so you have to say ***more narrowly***. However, that would give you:

> Your hands are too far apart. Grab the bar **more narrowly** and chin up.

That would probably be understood, but I wouldn't consider it idiomatic. The natural way to say it is to use more words, for example:

> Your hands are too far apart. **Bring them closer together** and chin up.

Now, you *could* use *narrow* **as a verb**, and people would understand the following:

> Your hands are too far apart. **Narrow them up** and chin up.

That is better than using *narrow* as an adverb, or using *more narrowly*, but is not as good as *bring them closer together*. You could also use *close them up* in the same way as *narrow them up* (that's *close* in its usual verb sense, not pronounced the same as *close* meaning *near*), which would be slightly more natural than *narrow them up*.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to weightlifting or related strength exercises, the distance between your hands when grasping the same bar is called a **grip**.  So in [body-building guides](https://www.shape.com/blogs/working-it-out/build-upper-body-strength-wide-grip-bench-press-vs-narrow-grip-bench-press), you will see exercises like a "**wide-grip** bench press" or a "**narrow-grip** (or **close-grip**) bench press." If you're asking someone to change their grip, then you can use the verbs **to widen** or **to narrow**:

> Your hands are too far apart. **Narrow your grip** and chin up.

or

> Your grip is too wide.  **Narrow it** and chin up.

Note that this use of **grip** to mean the distance between your gripping hands is somewhat *jargony* and specific to weightlifting.